# How to get the latest created file name and not the folder name using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The following code works well and gives me the require output with the file path.

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print latest_file
```

But if the file is created then it will give the file path but if the folder is created then it will give the folder path. Whereas I was expecting only the file and not the folder created in a  specific folder.

Kindly, suggest what I should do to get only the latest created file path and not the latest created folder path.

Comment: you can use os.path.isfile("filename") or os.path.isdir("directname") any one to filter that

Comment: @Narendra where I need to apply that command of check. I could not where I can place it in my code. Please explain a bit.

Comment: please see my answer given update there may be that could help you

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this using lambdas

```
filelist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
filelist = filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), filelist)
newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
```

The complete answer is posted here
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1526010

Comment: Where I specify the folder in which I need to search.. can you give me example please?

Comment: change "os.getcwd()" to your current/required directory

Comment: `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '.gitignore'` this is the error I got.. if though I have that file in my folder.

Comment: add another filter to not consider hidden files and filter start with "." after 2nd line

Comment: Should be in the same lines as below 

            `filelist = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('.'), filelist)` 

Please check the syntax. you can add as the third line once the directories are filtered

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing os already, then you don't need any other modules to achieve this. os has a module called `path` which handles path related functions.

To check if a path is directory or a file, you can check `os.path.isfile('/path/here')` which will return a boolean `true` or `false` depending on if the passed parameter is a file or not

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
import glob
import os

def check_file_status(path,direc=None):
    if direc==None:
        list_of_files = glob.glob(path)
        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        return latest_file
    else:
        new_path = direc+'/*'
        list_of_files = glob.glob(new_path)
        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        return latest_file

if __name__ =="__main__":

    path = '/your path to file/*'
    if os.path.isfile(check_file_status(path)):
            print(latest_file)

    elif os.path.isdir(check_file_status(path)):
            add_into_path = check_file_status(path)
            print(check_file_status(path,add_into_path))
```

Comment: What if it is not a file, then it won't give the latest file name ... I want to have the latest created file name any how... please can you check.

Comment: it should be either file or dir right then instead of "isfile" you can use "isdir"

Comment: No... only file no dir... I just want the latest created file.. even if the dir is created I should get the file and not the directory.